# Associate Like Buttons/Tweet Buttons with Individual Posts

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I Have Created a PHP Blog coded by myself. On the Homepage, all the recent posts are displayed.

I added the Code for Facebook Like and Tweet under the title of each post, but the Buttons work for the homepage, instead of each individual post. All the button contain same values.

The buttons work fine for each individual post when displayed as a single page with their own URL.

How can i Make the Like buttons work for individual posts from homepage.

Comment: "but the Buttons work for the homepage, instead of each individual post. All the button **contain same values.**" That would be your problem, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the URL of the individual blog entry in the Like button code. For example if using HTML5 version of Like button then something like:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example.com/blog/1" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example.com/blog/2" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

Or if using XFMBL version then:

```
<fb:like href="http://www.example.com/blog/1" send="false" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
<fb:like href="http://www.example.com/blog/2" send="false" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```